How to dualboot oneplus 7 pro
I have an extra mobile (one plus 7 pro) lying around, it has really good processor and alot of storage
I am thinking of making it remote server type something in which I can ssh into. Store my files or maybe learn about arm programming
One plus 7 pro comes with its propriety flavour of android called oxygen OS,
Is there any linux based OS that supports it. I think ubuntu touch may work.
But the problem is that most of these opensource OS, do not work on their proprietary hardware. At least not fully
Hence I want to be able to move back to Oxyge  os, whenever I want.
The only option i see is dual boot. But how do I dual boot. In PC you just press the boot key and the boot menu shows up, you can then boot from a pendrive.
How does this work in phones

How does this work in phones Short answer: It doesn't.

How do people install custom os then, how do kernel developers test their code on arm

There has to be UEFI firmware somewhere

ROMs are flashed to the device. ARM is not x86.

And Ubuntu Touch is long gone, Canonical dropped official support many years ago. Development is ongoing under the name UBports and is a community effort. Only a small number of devices has acceptable or "full" support, anything else is a DIY project.

@Tux I'm aware of no commercial phone that follows the UEFI spec; that just makes no sense for a phone, it's a device where the party that builds the operating system image simply inherently has the knowledge of where to put what, which peripherals there are, and how the hardware is initialized. Adding an UEFI step somewhere in there is just a complication with no benefit.

however, if you just want to "ssh into something", install termux on your android, and install sshd in that. Works beautifully.

termux is my last resort

@Tux unless you get into porting operating systems to unknown ARM systems that might be arbitrarily much locked down against replacement of the operating system, it's your only resort. That also makes it your last resort :)
